# Find two finite groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ such as:

Tags: finite-groups, sylow-theory

Find two finite groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ such as:

$1)$ $|G_1|=|G_2|$

$2)$ for all prime $p$ every $p$-sylow subgroup of $G_1$ isomorpic to $p$-sylow subgroup of $G_2$.

but $G_1\not\cong G_2$.

hello I tried to find an example but I couldn't find one please help me. 
I look on all the groups from order 6 (I choose this order randomly) but I don't know how to prove that every p-sylow subgroup of $G_1$ isomorpic to every p-sylow subgroup of $G_2$ for all primes p.

Comment: Maybe try to add what you have already tried.

Comment: Have you seen semi-direct product? If so $C_{21}$ and $C_3\ltimes C_7$ would do.

Comment: The first version of your question was not very detailed, but your edit is already better. You can take a look at this page to find some advice about what you should put in your question : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 4):

If $p, q$ are distinct primes then every two groups of order $pq$ will have isomorphic Sylow subgroups (being cyclic subgroups of order $p$ and $q$). So all you have to do is to find two nonisomorphic subgroups of order $pq$, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $S_3$.

Comment: thank you :) ,I am sorry but how do I prove that every p-sylow subgroups ane isomorpic?

Comment: @Rimon Every two cyclic groups of the same order are isomorphic. And every group of order $pq$ has both: subgroups of order $p$ and of order $q$ (Cauchy's theorem). These subgroups are necessary Sylow. That's everything you need.

Comment: thank you :)  I get it now